# Dynamic variable name referencing in SPSS syntax

Tags: macros, spss

I want to do certain actions on groups of variables. Each group has a specific index in the name. I don't want to repeat the syntax for each group. Is there a way to dynamically reference the variable names?

Below is the syntax. The 207 is the index that changes for each group of variables.

```
DO REPEAT aa= M9_207_1 to M9_207_99.
.....
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro to do this.

first define the macro:

```
define !MyMacro ()
!do !ndx=201 !to 207
  DO REPEAT aa= !concat("M9_",!ndx,"_1") to !concat("M9_",!ndx,"_99").
  .....
  END REPEAT.
  EXECUTE.
!doend
!enddefine.
```

then call it:

```
!MyMacro.
```

The macro defined here will run through indexes 201, 202, 203, etc'. If you need a more specific list of indexes, you can define the macro this way:

```
define !MyMacro (!pos=!cmdend)
!do !ndx !in(!1)
  DO REPEAT aa= !concat("M9_",!ndx,"_1") to !concat("M9_",!ndx,"_99").
  .....
  END REPEAT.
  EXECUTE.
!doend
!enddefine.
```

and then call it, giving the indexes (you have go specify each index individually):

!MyMacro 207 311 501 502 503 504 785.

Comment: Why do you concatenate !ind? Shouldn't it be !ndx?

Comment: Okay, I tried to run the following:
   define !MyMacro(!pos=!cmdend)
   !do !ndx !in (!1)
  DO REPEAT aa= !concat("Q1_",!ind,"_1") to !concat("Q1_",!ind,"_5").
   FREQ aa.
  END REPEAT.
  EXECUTE.
    !doend
    !enddefine.

  !MyMacro '010' '123'.

To which I got the errors:

>Error # 6835 in column 34.  Text: , 
>In a macro expression, a function name was not followed by a left parenthesis. 
>Execution of this command stops.

>Error # 4508 in column 23.  Text: _ 
>Unrecognized text appears on the DO REPEAT command.  It will be ignored. 
>Execution of this command stops.

Comment: 1. you are right about `!ind` and `!ndx` - I now corrected the code, should run better

Comment: 2. the syntax you ran has a few problems - (a) use my corrected syntax (b) you're missing an underline in `!concat("Q1_",!ind,"1")` (c) you can't use `freq` within a `do repeat` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could do some loop operation. I saw this kind of problem in R very often. I think the same idea would work in SPSS as well. Usually, I would try this:

```
for i in (1:207) {
  for j in (1:99) {
    M9[i,j] = ...
    certain actions...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.